How to create the "Circle of Fifths" in HTML/CSS/JS
Circle of Fifths
I want to create a clickable Circle of Fifths, with proper border and background colour like the image above, but have not been able to successfully create one in HTML/CSS. I'm looking for alternative solutions/mistakes in my approach.
My approach is the following:
CircleOfFifths.css

.key-pair:nth-child(1) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(120px) rotate(0deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(1) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(90px) rotate(0deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(2) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(30deg) translate(120px) rotate(-30deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(2) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(30deg) translate(90px) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(3) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(120px) rotate(-60deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(3) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(90px) rotate(-60deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(4) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(120px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(4) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(90px) rotate(-90deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(5) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translate(120px) rotate(-120deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(5) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(120deg) translate(90px) rotate(-120deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(6) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(150deg) translate(120px) rotate(-150deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(6) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(150deg) translate(90px) rotate(-150deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(7) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(120px) rotate(-180deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(7) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(90px) rotate(-180deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(8) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(210deg) translate(120px) rotate(-210deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(8) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(210deg) translate(90px) rotate(-210deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(9) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(240deg) translate(120px) rotate(-240deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(9) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(240deg) translate(90px) rotate(-240deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(10) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translate(120px) rotate(-270deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(10) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translate(90px) rotate(-270deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(11) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(300deg) translate(120px) rotate(-300deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(11) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(300deg) translate(90px) rotate(-300deg) translateY(-20px);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(12) .major-container {
    transform: rotate(330deg) translate(120px) rotate(-330deg);
}

.key-pair:nth-child(12) .minor-container {
    transform: rotate(330deg) translate(90px) rotate(-330deg) translateY(-20px);
}

CircleOfFifths.tsx - the actual component
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./CircleOfFifths.css"; // Import CSS file for custom styles

const keys = [
  { major: "C", minor: "Am" },
  { major: "G", minor: "Em" },
  { major: "D", minor: "Bm" },
  { major: "A", minor: "F#m" },
  { major: "E", minor: "C#m" },
  { major: "B", minor: "G#m" },
  { major: "F#", minor: "D#m" },
  { major: "Db", minor: "Bbm" },
  { major: "Ab", minor: "Fm" },
  { major: "Eb", minor: "Cm" },
  { major: "Bb", minor: "Gm" },
  { major: "F", minor: "Dm" },
];

const CircleOfFifths = () => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = useState("C");
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div
        className={`circle ${expanded ? "expanded" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#141429",
          color: "#758599",
          border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
        }}
      >
        {!expanded && <span className="selected-key">{selectedKey}</span>}
        {expanded && (
          <div className="circle-content">
            {keys.map((key, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="key-pair">
                <div
                  className="key-container major-container"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedKey(key.major);
                    setExpanded(false);
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="key">{key.major}</div>
                </div>
                <div
                  className="key-container minor-container"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedKey(key.minor);
                    setExpanded(false);
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="key">{key.minor}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CircleOfFifths;


This method correctly places the letters in a circle, but I cannot place a border correctly, and i suspect there is a better approach. Thanks for the help in advance.

Is that all styles in CircleOfFifths.css?

While the React component may be useful in answering the question with JavaScript/React, would you be able to add the HTML that your browser sees after React has rendered the content? That way it may be easier for us to offer a CSS approach.

@Shuo Yes. They are all styles of CircleOfFifths.css.

@DavidThomas Sure, but I believe that there is a more structured and cleaner approach to this, hence it would be helpful if you can provide me with the approach you would take in doing this. I doubt my approach would work, even with your help.
